# How to replace specific numbers (within a length limit) with specific letters?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I am trying to use `preg_replace` to change numbers to letters, but only numbers wrapped in `""` and not more than 7 characters in the substring.

Sample input string:

```
"3"sca"""co"1"str"0"ctor""r"3"t"0"r"1""locat"5"o"133""0"27""754a49b393c2a0"33"b97"332"cb7"3"c3c07"2""co"1"str"0"ctor""r"3"t"0"
```

The desired effect is for every qualifying `2` to become `d` and every qualifying `3` to become `e`.

These are examples of correct replacements:

- `"3"` becomes `e`
- `"23"` becomes `de`
- `"33"` becomes `ee`
- `"32"` becomes `de`
- `"333223"` becomes `eeedde`

My coding attempt:

```
$string = preg_replace("/\"322\"+/", "edd", $string);
$string = preg_replace("/\"233\"+/", "dee", $string);
$string = preg_replace("/\"32\"+/", "ed", $string);
$string = preg_replace("/\"23\"+/", "de", $string);
$string = preg_replace("/\"33\"+/", "e", $string);
$string = preg_replace("/\"333\"+/", "e", $string);
$string = preg_replace("/\"3\"+/", "e", $string);
$string = preg_replace("/\"3\"+/", "e", $string);
$string = preg_replace("/\"3\"+/", "e", $string);
$string = preg_replace("/\"3\"+/", "e", $string);
$string = preg_replace("/\"3\"+/", "e", $string);
```

How can I make all qualifying replacements with one preg_replace call?

Comment: Why are you trying to replace combinations, e.g. 322? You're overcomplicating this.

Comment: i am trying to 3rd party web scraping they hide get string in this if i replace i will get full get value

Comment: before replace 754a49b393c2a0"33"b97"332"cb7"3"c3c07"2" 
after replace
754a49b393c2a0eeb97eedcb7ec3c07d

Comment: then domain/get_id=754a49b393c2a0eeb97eedcb7ec3c07d

Comment: This seems like a flawed system. You only will have 10 characters to use.

Comment: i need to do if "only 1 to 7 characters and its number only"

Comment: You can only represent `b` through `l` through with this approach though, is that correct?

Comment: in "random" number but only 2 or 3 range like 223, 332, 33, 22 etc replace to dde, eed etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex to find either `2` or `3` between double-quotes from 1 to 7 times

`(?<=\")[23]{1,7}(?=\")`

> "233223322" won't be replaced with "deeddeedd" because it has more than 7 characters (9)

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/x9XbkN/1)

**Explanation**

`[23]{1,7}` Either `2` or `3` from 1 to 7 times

`(?<=\")` Precedeed by a double-quote

`(?=\")` Followed by a double-quote

**Snippet**

```
$text = '"3"sca"""co"1"str"0"ctor""r"3"t"0"r"1""locat"5"o"133""0"27""754a49b393c2a0"33"b97"332"cb7"3"c3c07"2""co"1"str"0"ct"233223322"or""r"3"t"0"';

$regex = '/(?<=\")[23]{1,7}(?=\")/';

$text = preg_replace_callback($regex, 
    function ($m) {
        switch ($m[0]) {
            case '2': return 'd';
            case '3': return 'e';
            // Add other cases here ...
        }
    },
    $text
);

echo $text;
```

[Online demo](https://repl.it/IIKa/4)

Answer (score 1):

To only replace those 2s and 3s inside quotes, you can do a `preg_replace_callback()` to accomplish that.

```
$before = '754a49b393c2a0"33"b97"332"cb7"3"c3c07"2"';

$after = preg_replace_callback(
        '/"([^"]+)"/',
        function ($matches) {
            return str_replace( array( '2', '3' ), array( 'd', 'e' ), $matches[1] );;
        },
        $before
    );

echo $after;
```

Comment: replace only in "number" and not more than 7 character

Comment: @Christian Edited to better match what you are doing.

Comment: how to set [2-9]{1,7} in this replace function ?

Answer (score 0):

First, my suggested code.  Then a review of the techniques employed on this page.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ag2HZ))

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/"([23]{1,7})"/',
        function ($m) {
            return str_replace(['2', '3'], ['d', 'e'], $m[1]);
        },
        $text
    );
```

---

Stephane Janicaud's and BA_Webimax's `preg_replace_callback()` answers have good components and not-so-good components in the execution, but the general logic is sound.  I'll take a moment to isolate some weakness/opportunities and offer some refinements.

### Regarding the pattern:

Stephane's pattern: `/(?<=\")[23]{1,7}(?=\")/` misunderstands the question and leaves the double quotes in the input string.  He writes the most appropriate character class and quantifier expression (one to seven occurrences), but the lookarounds are an unnecessarily heavy burden on pattern efficiency; also, the backslash before the double quotes is needless.  This pattern evaluates the OP's input string in a whopping [407 steps](https://regex101.com/r/sTA945/1).

Next in line is an adaptation of BA_Webimax's pattern.  His posted pattern does not offer the desired accuracy of only targeting `2` and `3`, but rather any non-double quote character.  For this comparison, I'll use `~"([23]{1,7})"~`.  This is a very tidy and effective pattern -- there are no lookarounds used, and the only drag is the capture group.  This pattern evaluates the string in a respectable [142 steps](https://regex101.com/r/sTA945/3).

### Regarding the character replacement:

Because Stephane is passing one to seven characters to the anonymous function AND the `switch` cases are ONLY checking for exact matches of `2` or `3`, his answer ends of mangling the string by **eradicating the 3rd and 4th matches**.  This makes the answer simply wrong. (The `Add other cases` comment is not a reasonable `yatta yatta` for developers to code up -- and why should they?)

BA_Webimax performs a smart, direct, efficient action using `str_replace()` on the first capture group string.

I checked the performance speeds on 3v4l.org and `str_replace()` edged out `strtr()` on php7.2 using the input string.  That said, executing a real benchmark would involve a larger volume of input data -- I just didn't go down that path.

Single-Function Replacements:

- `str_replace(['2', '3'], ['d', 'e'], $m[1]);`
- `strtr($m[1], ['2' => 'd', '3' => 'e']);`